# how can we use with method in laravel with where clause?

Tags: laravel, relationship

i need only those products where variants size field is tiny. what i should do ? above quering giving me all products but with empty variants

```
$result=$categories->with([
                'products' => function ($product) {
                    return $product->with([
                        'variants' => function ($variants) {
                            return $variants->where('size','tiny');
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            ])->get();
```

Comment: try $result=$categories->with(['products.variants'=>function($query){
    $query->whereHas(function($q){
        $q->where('size','tiny');
    });
}])->get();

Comment: you can simply do that using ```whereHas()``` which is mentioned in above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this.

```
$result=$categories->with([
                'products' => function ($product) {
                    return $product->whereHas(
                        'variants', function ($variants) {
                            return $variants->where('size','tiny');
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            ])->get();
```

Comment: yes you are right, i've done already but thank you so much

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).